# App on device with iOS 6.1 not compiling with base sdk 7.0 & deployment target 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode

In my project target settings, i have set the base SDK to ios 7.0 and deployment target to ios 6.1.

When i test my app with the simulator with iOS 6.1 or iOS 7.0, everything is fine.
The problem is that I just connected my iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1 installed and the project does not compile because of some iOS 7.0 calls...

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have copied the iOS 6.1 SDK into Xcode 5 from a copy of Xcode 4 then your device should be listed twice. If this is the case, the bottom option will compile your app against iOS 7 SDK and the top option (default) would compile your app against the iOS 6.1 SDK causing the compile errors

Comment: Oh man, thank you very much i never figured out why i was getting a duplicate in my device list !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to L14M333, when i connect my device, xCode shows display 2 times my device, the first one correspond to iOS 6.1 runtime, and the second one to iOS 7.0 runtime.

I just have to select the right one.

Comment: When I choose iOS 7 option I am getting WARNING: -[<AVCaptureConnection: 0x1466ca80> setVideoMinFrameDuration:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureDevice setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration
else getting WRANING: App on device with iOS 6.1 not compiling with base sdk 7.0 & deployment target 6.1 this warning.